# Redirect any urls to 404.html if not found in urls.py in django

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

How can I redirect any kind of url patterns to a created page "404.html" page if it doesn't exist in the urls.py rather than being shown the error by django.

Comment: Deactivate `DEBUG`. That would do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make a view that'll render your created 404.html and set it as handler404 in urls.py.

```
handler404 = 'app.views.404_view'
```

Django will render debug view if debug is enabled. Else it'll render 404 page as specified in handler404 for all types of pages if it doesn't exist.

Django documentation on [Customizing error views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views).

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11302845/303182) answer for a complete example.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way I can do the 404 handling without debug=false, because it is breaking my css as the static files are not loaded

Comment: @AnkanKumarGiri This is explained greatly in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail) thread. Make sure to read all answers.

Answer (score 2):

In your views.py, just add the following code (No need to change anything in urls.py).

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext


def handler404(request):
    response = render_to_response('404.html', {},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

Put a custom 404.html in templates directory.

[source : click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to change anything in your `view` or `url`.
Just do these 2 steps, in your `settings.py`, do the following

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

And in your app directory (myapp in this example), create `myapp/templates/404.html` where `404.html` is your custom error page. That is it.

Comment: NEVER use ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"] in production

Comment: `DEBUG = False`   
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1",'localhost']`

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project `settings.py` and set `DEBUG = True` to  `DEBUG = False`
Then Django redirects all NOT set patterns to not found.

In additional if you want to customize 404 template , in your project `urls.py`

set

handler404 = 'app.views.404_view'

then in your projects `view.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def handler404(request):
    response = render_to_response('404.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

and Finally, in your `templates` add `404.html` and fill it with what you want to show end user.