# Django How to redirect to 404 page if url patterns don't match

Tags: django, url

I am developing a blog with django,I want to redirect users to 404 page in case url patterns do not match. I know how to redirect to the 404 page when search queries to the database do not match i want to be able to do this when a url do not match any define in urlpatterns. How can i achieve this with django.

Comment: I think that django does this stuff without being programmed for that, doesn't it?

Comment: Maybe this can interest you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228818/redirect-any-urls-to-404-html-if-not-found-in-urls-py-in-django

Answer (score 0):

You can make the changes to setting.py file of you project directory and debug=false then it will render default 404 page 
Note Use this in the production or you can use handler404