# Redirect to login page on accepting a garbage url in Django

Tags: django, redirect, django-urls, url-validation

so I'm new to Django and I was making a webapp, named accounts. I would like to have a path method in my urlpatterns that sends me to the login page whenever I enter a url that is not mentioned in my other path methods.(NOTE: I have used the built-in login method)
How do I implement?

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, url
from . import views

from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

urlpatterns = [

    path('display/', views.display),
    path('', views.home),
    path('login/', login, {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'}),
    path('logout/', logout, {'template_name': 'accounts/logout.html'}),
    path('register/',views.register, name='register'),
    url('xxxx', login, {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'}) #here, I'd like to change 'xxxx'
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect any urls to 404.html if not found in urls.py in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228818/redirect-any-urls-to-404-html-if-not-found-in-urls-py-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an entry in your `views.py` that will handle the 404:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext


def handler404(request):
    response = render_to_response('your_login_template.html', {},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

Then in your `urls.py` you can specify it:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import handler404, handler500
handler404 = 'views.handler404'
```

Note that this will only work if `DEBUG=False` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: okay, so how do I send the control from the urls.py to the views once it doesn't find a matching entity?

Comment: @SachinKukreja yeah, good point, you need to set DEBUG=False for this to work

Comment: umm... this doesn't seem to work. I got an ALLOWED HOSTS related error, i modified it to ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] but it still shows a page not found. Do i have to import a function or something?

Comment: Try setting it to localhost (where I assume you're testing) and also make sure that it wasn't redefined as [] elsewhere
What's the error exactly?

Comment: Page Not Found. But it's just as a text, not as the error handling page that we usually have

Comment: Also, I am making a game which will be played by multiple people, I hope changing it to localhost won't cause an issue

Comment: Try setting the response to 200?