# 404 page managed by angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, django, angular-ui-router

I have a django backend and a angular/ui-router frontend. I would like to handle 404 errors (and 400, 403 and 500) on the frontend side. Meaning:

1. A client send a bad url (page not found)
2. I catch the exception with a custom error handler on the backend side
3. Return the 404
4. Magic!
5. The frontend redirects to something like www.example.com/#/error404

I could just return a django.shortcut.redirect from the backend side but I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16238266/2603925) that crawlers from search engines do not like when you do not return a 404 error code on unknown page. With a redirect I'd be returning a 302...

Or is it just wrong to manage error pages on the client side ? This would be a shame because everything is managed by the frontend (header, footer, etc) so the 404 page would not be following the standard page layout.

Answer (score 0):

Check out interceptors here,
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Once you set that up, you should be able to redirect to a page according to the error you process.